# Can QFrame be triggered by its childs elements

Tags: python, pyqt5, qframe

When an item (spinBox, LineEdit etc) changes its value in GUI (via designer) I set a certain button's enable status. For example:

```
self.ui.lineEdit_1.textChanged.connect(self.pushButton_status)
self.ui.checkBox_1.stateChanged.connect(self.pushButton_status)
self.ui.spinBox_1.valueChanged.connect(self.pushButton_status)
self.ui.spinBox_2.valueChanged.connect(self.pushButton_status)
self.ui.spinBox_3.valueChanged.connect(self.pushButton_status)
self.ui.spinBox_4.valueChanged.connect(self.pushButton_status)
```

This works fine. Though there are lots of lines here (and even more in the actual code). I have all of these items inside a frame (QFrame). So I was wondering if it is possible to do something like:

```
self.ui.frame_1.childValueChanged.connect(self.pushButton_status)
```

which could perhaps stand for all the items inside of it. Is there any way within this logic that could do what I am looking for? If so.. how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to do what you want, but there is a maintainable way to do it, in this case you just have to filter the type of widget and indicate which signal you will use by adding more options to the function, in your case:

```
def connectToChildrens(parentWidget, slot):
    # get all the children that are widget
    for children in parentWidget.findChildren(QtWidgets.QWidget): 
        # filter if the class that belongs to the object is QLineEdit
        if isinstance(children, QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
            # Connect the signal with the default slot.
            children.textChanged.connect(slot)
        elif isinstance(children, QtWidgets.QCheckBox):
            children.stateChanged.connect(slot)
        elif isinstance(children, QtWidgets.QSpinBox):
            children.valueChanged.connect(slot)
```

And then you use it in the following way:

```
class MyDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None): 
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(parent) 
        self.ui = Ui_MyDialog() 
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        connectToChildrens(self.ui.frame_1, self.pushButton_status)
```

Comment: Thank you @eyllanesc. How would you use this under the class's __init__ ? I mean how is it triggered? When I write self.ui.lineEdit_1.textChanged.connect(self.pushButton_status) under init, it tells the program that if the lineEdit text is changed run the method within the parathenses. I am trying to understand how your code is implemented.

Comment: @Mr.Robot explain your question better please.

Comment: @Mr.Robot If you want to know the operation of the signals and slots you can read the following: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html, but by summarizing a signal when it is issued internally, Qt calls the connected slots.

Comment: @Mr.Robot You could also read the following documentation: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html

Comment: `class MyDialog(QDialog):`

    `def __init__(self, parent=None):`
        `super(MyDialog, self).__init__(parent)`
        `self.ui = Ui_MyDialog()`
        `self.ui.setupUi(self)`

Basically the above is how my classes start with. Since your code didn't start with the classic self.ui which is normally what I use under the __init__ constructor I got confused. After your update, I think I got it now. I just use it the way you provide. No self.ui needed...

I have been coding very shortly so OOP sometimes confuses me. Apologies...

Thank you for your answer @eyllanesc